# How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a data frame with one (string) column and I'd like to split it into two (string) columns, with one column header as '`fips'` and the other `'row'`

My dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
          row
0    00000 UNITED STATES
1    01000 ALABAMA
2    01001 Autauga County, AL
3    01003 Baldwin County, AL
4    01005 Barbour County, AL
```

I do not know how to use `df.row.str[:]` to achieve my goal of splitting the row cell. I can use `df['fips'] = hello` to add a new column and populate it with `hello`. Any ideas?

```
         fips       row
0    00000 UNITED STATES
1    01000 ALABAMA 
2    01001 Autauga County, AL
3    01003 Baldwin County, AL
4    01005 Barbour County, AL
```

Comment: how did you load your data into pandas? You might be able to laod the data in your desired format using `read_table()` or  `read_fwf()`

Comment: *"How to split a column"* has different answers depending on whether the column is string, list, or something else, also what format (e.g. 'formatted string' like an address, for which you might need to use a regex. Here you have a string column with fixed-width format ("ZZZZZ placename...") so we know the zipcode is characters 0:4 and the placename is characters 6:

Answer (score 184, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this here's one approach:

```
                            row
    0       00000 UNITED STATES
    1             01000 ALABAMA
    2  01001 Autauga County, AL
    3  01003 Baldwin County, AL
    4  01005 Barbour County, AL
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.row.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),
                                 columns = ['fips','row'])
```

```
   fips                 row
0  00000       UNITED STATES
1  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

Comment: Be aware that .tolist() will remove any indexes you had, so your new Dataframe will be reindexed from 0 (It doesn't matter in your specific case).

Comment: @Crashthatch -- then again you can just add `index = df.index` and you are good.

Comment: what if one cell can't be split?

Comment: @Nisba: If any cell can't be split (e.g. string doesn't contain any space for this case) it will still work but one part of the split will be empty. Other situations will happen in case you have mixed types in the column with at least one cell containing any number type. Then the `split` method returns NaN and the `tolist` method will return this value as is (NaN) which will result in `ValueError` (to overcome this issue you can cast it to string type before splitting). I recommend you to try it on your own it's the best way of learning :-)

Comment: @techkuz: Are you sure your `df` has the `row` column header? You may think it's some kind of DataFrame attribute but it's quite clear this is the name of the column. It's up to you how you create and define your column headers so if you use different one use it (e.g. `df.my_column_name.split(...)`).

Answer (score 792):

## TL;DR version:

For the simple case of:

- I have a text column with a delimiter and I want two columns

The simplest solution is:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

You must use `expand=True` if your strings have a non-uniform number of splits and you want `None` to replace the missing values.

Notice how, in either case, the `.tolist()` method is not necessary. Neither is `zip()`.

## In detail:

[Andy Hayden's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21296915/1273938) is most excellent in demonstrating the power of the [`str.extract()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method.

But for a simple split over a known separator (like, splitting by dashes, or splitting by whitespace), the [`.str.split()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) method is enough<sup>1</sup>. It operates on a column (Series) of strings, and returns a column (Series) of lists:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'AB': ['A1-B1', 'A2-B2']})
>>> df

      AB
0  A1-B1
1  A2-B2
>>> df['AB_split'] = df['AB'].str.split('-')
>>> df

      AB  AB_split
0  A1-B1  [A1, B1]
1  A2-B2  [A2, B2]
```

<sub>1: If you're unsure what the first two parameters of `.str.split()` do,
I recommend the docs for the [plain Python version of the method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).</sub>

But how do you go from:

- a column containing two-element lists

to:

- two columns, each containing the respective element of the lists?

Well, we need to take a closer look at the `.str` attribute of a column.

It's a magical object that is used to collect methods that treat each element in a column as a string, and then apply the respective method in each element as efficient as possible:

```
>>> upper_lower_df = pd.DataFrame({"U": ["A", "B", "C"]})
>>> upper_lower_df

   U
0  A
1  B
2  C
>>> upper_lower_df["L"] = upper_lower_df["U"].str.lower()
>>> upper_lower_df

   U  L
0  A  a
1  B  b
2  C  c
```

But it also has an "indexing" interface for getting each element of a string by its index:

```
>>> df['AB'].str[0]

0    A
1    A
Name: AB, dtype: object

>>> df['AB'].str[1]

0    1
1    2
Name: AB, dtype: object
```

Of course, this indexing interface of `.str` doesn't really care if each element it's indexing is actually a string, as long as it can be indexed, so:

```
>>> df['AB'].str.split('-', 1).str[0]

0    A1
1    A2
Name: AB, dtype: object

>>> df['AB'].str.split('-', 1).str[1]

0    B1
1    B2
Name: AB, dtype: object
```

Then, it's a simple matter of taking advantage of the Python tuple unpacking of iterables to do

```
>>> df['A'], df['B'] = df['AB'].str.split('-', n=1).str
>>> df

      AB  AB_split   A   B
0  A1-B1  [A1, B1]  A1  B1
1  A2-B2  [A2, B2]  A2  B2
```

Of course, getting a DataFrame out of splitting a column of strings is so useful that the `.str.split()` method can do it for you with the `expand=True` parameter:

```
>>> df['AB'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)

    0   1
0  A1  B1
1  A2  B2
```

So, another way of accomplishing what we wanted is to do:

```
>>> df = df[['AB']]
>>> df

      AB
0  A1-B1
1  A2-B2

>>> df.join(df['AB'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B'}))

      AB   A   B
0  A1-B1  A1  B1
1  A2-B2  A2  B2
```

The `expand=True` version, although longer, has a distinct advantage over the tuple unpacking method. Tuple unpacking doesn't deal well with splits of different lengths:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'AB': ['A1-B1', 'A2-B2', 'A3-B3-C3']})
>>> df
         AB
0     A1-B1
1     A2-B2
2  A3-B3-C3
>>> df['A'], df['B'], df['C'] = df['AB'].str.split('-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]    
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
>>>
```

But `expand=True` handles it nicely by placing `None` in the columns for which there aren't enough "splits":

```
>>> df.join(
...     df['AB'].str.split('-', expand=True).rename(
...         columns={0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'}
...     )
... )
         AB   A   B     C
0     A1-B1  A1  B1  None
1     A2-B2  A2  B2  None
2  A3-B3-C3  A3  B3    C3
```

Comment: df['A'], df['B'] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', 1).str

What is the meaning of '1' in split(' ', 1) ?

Comment: @Hariprasad, it's the maximum number of splits. I've added a link to the [docs for the Python Version of the `.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which explain the first two parameters better than the Pandas docs.

Comment: pandas 1.0.0 reports "FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases."

Comment: This works under Python 1.0.1. `df.join(df['AB'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B'}))`

Comment: @MartienLubberink Instead of that you can assign to a DataFrame sub-slice: `df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)`

Comment: This is great, but how do you split when you have two different split areas?  Long story short: I'm reading in SQL and want to take the FROM statement and split it into database, schema, table, alias.  Database, schema, and table are easy - I split at the period/dot.  But, alias?  Sometimes there could be just a space and sometimes people would put in AS.  What would you suggest?

Comment: @DataGirl, for that I'd suggest [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with an appropriately written regex.

Comment: If I use this I get `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: @JohnVandivier, It's possible none of the values in your split column achieve the number of splits you expect, so the split operation is not producing the number of columns you're trying to assign. Check [this pandas bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35807) and perhaps [this other S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585193/pandas-error-in-python-columns-must-be-same-length-as-key). I'll try to think of ways to expand this answer to overcome this issue, or at least warn about it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. How can I split an object such as 324786ABCD or -577.89CBC into two columns, one with text, one with the numbers?

Comment: @Baobab, I think your comment should be its own Stack Overflow question, since this question is about splitting on separators. But in a hunch I'd suggest you try the [`.str.extract()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21296915/1273938) method with a regex like `r'(?P<numbers>[+-.\d]+)(?P<letters>[a-zA-Z]+)'`.

Comment: @Hariprasad  your question , sample[meta_desc_as_column_name] = sample['comb'].str.split('|', 5, expand=True)

Comment: @Hariprasad  Lets take Example :- sample[['X','Y','Z']] = sample['pattern'].str.split('|', 3, expand=True) ,  Lets assume , you have string pattern like this "A|B|C" and you want to create a new column in same data frame , as  X , Y , Z with pattern column spitted values. So the purpose of giving 3 here is to tell break my string 3 times and fill respective values in it.  Let's say if you put 2  that time output will look like this: A , B|C means total of 2 values.

Comment: With Pandas 2.0.0 I must use this syntax or else I get an error: `df['AB'].str.split(pat=' ', n=1, expand=True)`

Comment: If there are more than many columns and you don't know the number, you can just keep n undefined.

Comment: @SonghuaHu, right. If one doesn't specify `n`, they must take care that the dataframe resulting from `str.split(..., expand=True)` will have an arbitrary number of columns, and deal with it appropriately.

Answer (score 79):

You can [extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the different parts out quite neatly using a regex pattern:

```
In [11]: df.row.str.extract('(?P<fips>\d{5})((?P<state>[A-Z ]*$)|(?P<county>.*?), (?P<state_code>[A-Z]{2}$))')
Out[11]: 
    fips                    1           state           county state_code
0  00000        UNITED STATES   UNITED STATES              NaN        NaN
1  01000              ALABAMA         ALABAMA              NaN        NaN
2  01001   Autauga County, AL             NaN   Autauga County         AL
3  01003   Baldwin County, AL             NaN   Baldwin County         AL
4  01005   Barbour County, AL             NaN   Barbour County         AL

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

---

To explain the somewhat long regex:

```
(?P<fips>\d{5})
```

- Matches the five digits (`\d`) and names them `"fips"`.

The next part:

```
((?P<state>[A-Z ]*$)|(?P<county>.*?), (?P<state_code>[A-Z]{2}$))
```

Does either (`|`) one of two things:

```
(?P<state>[A-Z ]*$)
```

- Matches any number (`*`) of capital letters or spaces (`[A-Z ]`) and names this `"state"` before the end of the string (`$`),

or

```
(?P<county>.*?), (?P<state_code>[A-Z]{2}$))
```

- matches anything else (`.*`) then
- a comma and a space then
- matches the two digit `state_code` before the end of the string (`$`).

*In the example:*
*Note that the first two rows hit the "state" (leaving NaN in  the county and state_code columns), whilst the last three hit the county, state_code (leaving NaN in the state column).*

Comment: This is definitely the best solution but it might be a bit overwhelming to some with the very extensive regex. Why not do that as a part 2 and have part 1 with just the fips and row columns?

Comment: @josh that's a good point, whilst the individual parts of the regex are "easy" to understand, long regex can get complicated quickly. I added some explanation for future readers! (I also had to update the link to the docs which explains the `(?P<label>...)` syntax! I've no idea why I went for the more complex regex, clearly the simple one could work hmmmm

Comment: Looks much friendlier. I'm glad you did because it had me look at the docs to understand the `<group_name>`. Now I know it it makes my code very succinct.

Comment: But does not this return only the first match for repeating patterns, like `123-456` if you search for digits with `(\d+)`? In other words, you have to know the exact pattern you are searching for, it can't dynamically grow to accommodate `123`, `123-456` and `123-456-789`

Answer (score 56):

```
df[['fips', 'row']] = df['row'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace (default separator) and parameter `expand=True` for `DataFrame` with assign to new columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'row': ['00000 UNITED STATES', '01000 ALABAMA', 
                           '01001 Autauga County, AL', '01003 Baldwin County, AL', 
                           '01005 Barbour County, AL']})
print (df)
                        row
0       00000 UNITED STATES
1             01000 ALABAMA
2  01001 Autauga County, AL
3  01003 Baldwin County, AL
4  01005 Barbour County, AL



df[['a','b']] = df['row'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
                        row      a                   b
0       00000 UNITED STATES  00000       UNITED STATES
1             01000 ALABAMA  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001 Autauga County, AL  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003 Baldwin County, AL  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005 Barbour County, AL  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

Modification if need remove original column with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html)

```
df[['a','b']] = df.pop('row').str.split(n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
       a                   b
0  00000       UNITED STATES
1  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

What is same like:

```
df[['a','b']] = df['row'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df = df.drop('row', axis=1)
print (df)

       a                   b
0  00000       UNITED STATES
1  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

---

If get error:

```
#remove n=1 for split by all whitespaces
df[['a','b']] = df['row'].str.split(expand=True)
```

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

You can check and it return 4 column `DataFrame`, not only 2:

```
print (df['row'].str.split(expand=True))
       0        1        2     3
0  00000   UNITED   STATES  None
1  01000  ALABAMA     None  None
2  01001  Autauga  County,    AL
3  01003  Baldwin  County,    AL
4  01005  Barbour  County,    AL
```

Then solution is append new `DataFrame` by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'row': ['00000 UNITED STATES', '01000 ALABAMA', 
                           '01001 Autauga County, AL', '01003 Baldwin County, AL', 
                           '01005 Barbour County, AL'],
                    'a':range(5)})
print (df)
   a                       row
0  0       00000 UNITED STATES
1  1             01000 ALABAMA
2  2  01001 Autauga County, AL
3  3  01003 Baldwin County, AL
4  4  01005 Barbour County, AL

df = df.join(df['row'].str.split(expand=True))
print (df)

   a                       row      0        1        2     3
0  0       00000 UNITED STATES  00000   UNITED   STATES  None
1  1             01000 ALABAMA  01000  ALABAMA     None  None
2  2  01001 Autauga County, AL  01001  Autauga  County,    AL
3  3  01003 Baldwin County, AL  01003  Baldwin  County,    AL
4  4  01005 Barbour County, AL  01005  Barbour  County,    AL
```

With remove original column (if there are also another columns):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('row').str.split(expand=True))
print (df)
   a      0        1        2     3
0  0  00000   UNITED   STATES  None
1  1  01000  ALABAMA     None  None
2  2  01001  Autauga  County,    AL
3  3  01003  Baldwin  County,    AL
4  4  01005  Barbour  County,    AL
```

Comment: If there are two such columns, which need to be split, it returns: `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified:`

Answer (score 26):

If you don't want to create a new dataframe, or if your dataframe has more columns than just the ones you want to split, you could:

```
df["flips"], df["row_name"] = zip(*df["row"].str.split().tolist())
del df["row"]
```

Comment: I get a `zip argument #1 must support iteration` error, python 2.7

Answer (score 14):

Use `df.assign` to create a new df. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

```py
split = df_selected['name'].str.split(',', 1, expand=True)
df_split = df_selected.assign(first_name=split[0], last_name=split[1])
df_split.drop('name', 1, inplace=True)
```

Or in method chain form:

```
df_split = (df_selected
            .assign(list_col=lambda df: df['name'].str.split(',', 1, expand=False),
                    first_name=lambda df: df.list_col.str[0],
                    last_name=lambda df: df.list_col.str[1])
            .drop(columns=['list_col']))
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to split a string into more than two columns based on a delimiter you can omit the 'maximum splits' parameter.
You can use:

```
df['column_name'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

This will automatically create as many columns as the maximum number of fields included in any of your initial strings.

Answer (score 11):

Surprised I haven't seen this one yet. If you only need **two** splits, I highly recommend. . .

## **[`Series.str.partition`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.partition.html)**

`partition` performs one split on the separator, and is generally quite performant.

```
df['row'].str.partition(' ')[[0, 2]]

       0                   2
0  00000       UNITED STATES
1  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

If you need to rename the rows,

```
df['row'].str.partition(' ')[[0, 2]].rename({0: 'fips', 2: 'row'}, axis=1)

    fips                 row
0  00000       UNITED STATES
1  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

If you need to join this back to the original, use `join` or `concat`:

```
df.join(df['row'].str.partition(' ')[[0, 2]])
```

```
pd.concat([df, df['row'].str.partition(' ')[[0, 2]]], axis=1)

                        row      0                   2
0       00000 UNITED STATES  00000       UNITED STATES
1             01000 ALABAMA  01000             ALABAMA
2  01001 Autauga County, AL  01001  Autauga County, AL
3  01003 Baldwin County, AL  01003  Baldwin County, AL
4  01005 Barbour County, AL  01005  Barbour County, AL
```

Answer (score 3):

I saw that no one had used the slice method, so here I put my 2 cents here.

```
df["<col_name>"].str.slice(stop=5)
df["<col_name>"].str.slice(start=6)
```

This method will create two new columns.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer exporting the corresponding pandas series (i.e. the columns I need), using the **apply** function to split the column content into multiple series and then **join** the generated columns to the existing DataFrame. Of course, the source column should be removed.

e.g.

```
 col1 = df["<col_name>"].apply(<function>)
 col2 = ...
 df = df.join(col1.to_frame(name="<name1>"))
 df = df.join(col2.toframe(name="<name2>"))
 df = df.drop(["<col_name>"], axis=1)
```

To split two words strings function should be something like that:

```
lambda x: x.split(" ")[0] # for the first element
lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1] # for the last element
```

Answer (score 0):

**FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split except for the argument 'pat' will be keyword-only.**

Just a small update to the first answer.
If you encounter the warning message above, (I am currently using the `pd.__version__` = 1.5.3) that in future versions will become an error, you can avoid it by adding the name of the arguments to your arguments. So, the "simplest solution" that LeoRochael posted:

```py
# Will raise a warning or error
df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

should be:

```py
# For newer pandas versions
df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Other examples also posted here will need the name of the argument as well.

```py
# For instance, if you want to split and remove the splitted columns
df[['A','B']] = df.pop('AB').str.split(n=1, expand=True)
```

I hope this can help.