# parse string into columns python pandas /xa0 in stead of white space

Tags: python, pandas

How do I quickly make new columns that hold the three chunks contained in the column 'File'?

recieved messy data like this

```
d = {   'File' : pd.Series(['firstname lastname                   05/31/1996                     9999999999  ', 'FN SometimesMiddileInitial. LN                    05/31/1996                 9999999999  ']), 
    'Status' : pd.Series([0., 0.]), 
    'Error' : pd.Series([2., 2.])}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

UPDATE
In reality, i'm starting from a very messy excel file and my data has '\xa0 \xa0' between string characters.
so my first attempt looks like

```
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelFile
import pandas as pd
location = r'c:/users/meinzerc/Desktop/table.xlsx'
xls = ExcelFile(location)
table = xls.parse('Sheet1')
splitdf = df['File'].str.split('\s*)
```

My attempt doesn't work at all.  WHY?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame, how do i split a column into two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex to pick up at least two spaces:

```
In [11]: df.File.str.split('\s\s+')
Out[11]: 
0       [firstname lastname, 05/31/1996, 9999999999, ]
1    [FN SometimesMiddileInitial. LN, 05/31/1996, 9...
Name: File, dtype: object
```

Perhaps a better option is to use [extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) (and perhaps there is a neater regex!!):

```
In [12]: df.File.str.extract('\s*(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(?P<number>\w+)\s*')
Out[12]: 
                             name        date      number
0              firstname lastname  05/31/1996  9999999999
1  FN SometimesMiddileInitial. LN  05/31/1996  9999999999

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you Andy.  simple and perfect.. in practice, but when i tried it on my excel df, df.values showed '\xa0 \xa0' instead of white space.  I've never dealt with that before, so i tried df.File.str.split('\\xa0+\s*\\xa0*') and finally got it!  Maybe i can edit my original question to elicit feedback for \xa0?  also, i'll try the extract!  looks great, i like extract because it is more intential!

Comment: @ChetMeinzer that's a latin-1 codepoint for non-breaking whitespace. I'm afraid you'll get bitten by this kind of thing occasionally so it's a good idea to check the results a bit after, and see what bites next :). Another alternative might be to `.replace('\xa0', ' ')` first.

Comment: I think you are right.  If i can get that out of there, then it will be more normal to adjust.  Thanks again!