# Python pandas.read_csv split column into multiple new columns using comma to separate

Tags: python, pandas, split

I've used  pandas.read_csv to load in a file.

I've stored the file into a variable.
The first column is a series of numbers separated by a comma (,)
I want to split these numbers, and put each number to a new column.

I can't seem to find the write functionality for pandas.dataframe.

Side Note
I would prefer a different library for loading in my file, but pandas
provides some other different functionality which I need.

My Code:

`Data = pandas.read_csv(pathFile,header=None)`

doing: `print Data` gives me:

```
   0                          1         2          ...
0 [2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0]   0         0.25       ...
```

(as you can see its a date)

Question: How to split/separate each number 
and save it in a new array

p.s. I'm trying to achieve the same thing the matlab method  `datevec()` does

Comment: Take a look at a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CSV data looks like

```
"[2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0]",0,0.25
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('data', header=None)
dates, df = df[0], df.iloc[:, 1:]
df = pd.concat([df, dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x)))], axis=1,
               ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   0     1     2  3   4  5   6  7
0  0  0.25  2014  8  26  5  30  0
```

with the values parsed as numeric values.

---

How it works:

```
dates, df = df[0], df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

peels off the first column, and reassigns `df` to the rest of the DataFrame:

```
In [217]: dates
Out[217]: 
0    [2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

`dates` contains strings:

```
In [218]: dates.iloc[0]
Out[218]: '[2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0]'
```

We can convert these to a list using `json.loads`:

```
In [219]: import json

In [220]: json.loads(dates.iloc[0])
Out[220]: [2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0]

In [221]: type(json.loads(dates.iloc[0]))
Out[221]: list
```

We can do this for each row of `dates` by using `apply`:

```
In [222]: dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x)))
Out[222]: 
      0  1   2  3   4  5
0  2014  8  26  5  30  0
```

By making `lambda`, above, return a Series, `apply` will return a DataFrame,
with the index of the Series becoming the column index of the DataFrame.

Now we can use `pd.concat` to concatenate this DataFrame with `df`:

```
In [228]: df = pd.concat([df, dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x)))], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

In [229]: df
Out[229]: 
   0     1     2  3   4  5   6  7
0  0  0.25  2014  8  26  5  30  0

In [230]: df.dtypes
Out[230]: 
0      int64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
4    float64
5    float64
6    float64
7    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Tnx! Great explanation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df
#                   datestr
#0  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0
#1  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0
#2  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0
#3  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0
#4  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0

# each entry is a string
df.datestr[0]
#'2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0'
```

Then

```
date_order = ('year', 'month','day','hour','minute','sec') # order matters here, should match the datestr column 

for i,col in enumerate( date_order):
    df[col] = df.datestr.map( lambda x: x.split(',')[i].strip() )

#df
#                   datestr  year month day hour minute  sec
#0  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0  2014     8  26    5     30  0.0
#1  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0  2014     8  26    5     30  0.0
#2  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0  2014     8  26    5     30  0.0
#3  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0  2014     8  26    5     30  0.0
#4  2014, 8, 26, 5, 30, 0.0  2014     8  26    5     30  0.0
```