# Delimit a specific column and add them as columns in CSV (Python3, CSV)

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file that has several columns that I first delimit by colon (;).  However, ONE column is delimited by a pipe | and I would like to delimit this column and create new columns.

Input:

```
  Column 1    Column 2      Column 3
     1           2          3|4|5
     6           7          6|7|8
     10          11         12|13|14
```

Desired Output:

```
  Column 1   Column 2      ID    Age  Height
     1          2          3      4    5 
     6          7          6      7    8
     10         11         12     13   14
```

My code so far delimits the first time by ; and then converts to DF (which is my desired end format)

```
delimit = list(csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=';'))
df = pd.DataFrame(delimit)
```

Comment: you can parse the last column and [split it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show exactly what the data looks like (you say it's delimited by semicolons, but your examples don't have any), but if it looks like

```
Column 1;Column 2;Column 3
1;2;3|4|5
6;7;6|7|8
10;11;12|13|14
```

You could do something like

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="[;|]", engine='python', skiprows=1, 
                     names=["Column 1", "Column 2", "ID", "Age", "Height"])
>>> df
   Column 1  Column 2  ID  Age  Height
0         1         2   3    4       5
1         6         7   6    7       8
2        10        11  12   13      14
```

This works by using a regex separator meaning "either `;` or `|`" and forcing the column names manually.

Alternatively, you could do it in a few steps:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";")
>>> df
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
0         1         2     3|4|5
1         6         7     6|7|8
2        10        11  12|13|14
>>> c3 = df.pop("Column 3").str.split("|", expand=True)
>>> c3.columns = ["ID", "Age", "Height"]
>>> df.join(c3)
   Column 1  Column 2  ID Age Height
0         1         2   3   4      5
1         6         7   6   7      8
2        10        11  12  13     14
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run the second half of your code: TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: @user3682157: you're probably using an older version of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimit = list(csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=';'))

for row in delimit:
    piped = row.pop()
    row.extend(piped.split('|'))

df = pd.DataFrame(delimit)
```

`delimit` ends up looking like:

```
[
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    ['6', '7', '6', '7', '8'],
    ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually much faster to use the csv lib and str.replace:

```
import csv
with open("test.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    # itertools.imap python2
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(csv.reader(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().replace("|", ";"), f), delimiter=";"),
                                   columns=["Column 1", "Column 2", "ID", "Age", "Height"]).astype(int)
```

Some timings:

```
In [35]: %%timeit
pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="[;|]", engine='python', skiprows=1,
                     names=["Column 1", "Column 2", "ID", "Age", "Height"])
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop

In [36]: %%timeit                                                             
with open("test.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(csv.reader(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().replace("|", ";"), f),delimiter=";"),
                               columns=["Column 1", "Column 2", "ID", "Age", "Height"]).astype(int)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.05 ms per loop
```

You could just str.split:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(map(lambda x: x.rstrip().replace("|", ";").split(";"), f),
                                   columns=["Column 1", "Column 2", "ID", "Age", "Height"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution for myself:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(delimit)
s = df['Column 3'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('|')))
frame = pd.DataFrame(s)
frame.rename(columns={0: 'ID',1:'Height',2:'Age'}, inplace=True)
result = pd.concat([df, frame], axis=1)
```