# Pandas split column into multiple columns by comma

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, split

I am trying to split a column into multiple columns based on comma/space separation.

My dataframe currently looks like

```
     KEYS                                                  1
0   FIT-4270                                          4000.0439
1   FIT-4269                                          4000.0420, 4000.0471
2   FIT-4268                                          4000.0419
3   FIT-4266                                          4000.0499
4   FIT-4265                                          4000.0490, 4000.0499, 4000.0500, 4000.0504,
```

I would like

```
   KEYS                                                  1           2            3        4 
0   FIT-4270                                          4000.0439
1   FIT-4269                                          4000.0420  4000.0471
2   FIT-4268                                          4000.0419
3   FIT-4266                                          4000.0499
4   FIT-4265                                          4000.0490  4000.0499  4000.0500  4000.0504
```

My code currently removes The KEYS column and I'm not sure why. Could anyone improve or help fix the issue?

```
v = dfcleancsv[1]

#splits the columns by spaces into new columns but removes KEYS?

dfcleancsv = dfcleancsv[1].str.split(' ').apply(Series, 1)
```

Comment: You want `pd.concat([df[[0]], df[1].str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)` IIUC

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In case someone else wants to split a single column (deliminated by a value) into multiple columns - try this:

```
series.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

This answered the question I came here looking for.

Credit to [EdChum's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) code that includes adding the split columns back to the dataframe.

```
pd.concat([df[[0]], df[1].str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

**Note**: The first argument `df[[0]]` is `DataFrame`.

The second argument `df[1].str.split` is the series that you want to split.

[split Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

[concat Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Answer (score 13):

Using Edchums answer of

```
pd.concat([df[[0]], df[1].str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

I was able to solve it by substituting my variables.

```
dfcleancsv = pd.concat([dfcleancsv['KEYS'], dfcleancsv[1].str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 9):

The OP had a variable number of output columns.
In the particular case of a fixed number of output columns another elegant solution to name the resulting columns is to use a multiple assignation.

Load a sample dataset and reshape it to long format to obtain a variable
called `organ_dimension`.

```
import seaborn
iris = seaborn.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris.melt(id_vars='species', var_name='organ_dimension', value_name='value')
```

Split the `organ_dimension` variable in 2 variables `organ` and `dimension` based on the `_` separator.

```
df[['organ', 'dimension']] = df['organ_dimension'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df.head()

Out[10]: 
  species organ_dimension  value  organ dimension
0  setosa    sepal_length    5.1  sepal    length
1  setosa    sepal_length    4.9  sepal    length
2  setosa    sepal_length    4.7  sepal    length
3  setosa    sepal_length    4.6  sepal    length
4  setosa    sepal_length    5.0  sepal    length
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358924/2641825) *"How to split a column into two columns?"*

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to use is, vectorization

```
df = df.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this should work:

```
df = pd.concat([df['KEYS'],df[1].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers seemed to work for me.  This worked after reading the docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html.  This also expanded into new columns

```
df_new = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
Responder_id    LanguagesWorkedWith
0   1   HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript;Python
1   2   C++;HTML/CSS;Python
2   3   HTML/CSS
3   4   C;C++;C#;Python;SQL
4   5   C++;HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript;Python;SQL;VBA
... ... ...
87564   88182   HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript
87565   88212   HTML/CSS;JavaScript;Python
87566   88282   Bash/Shell/PowerShell;Go;HTML/CSS;JavaScript;W...
87567   88377   HTML/CSS;JavaScript;Other(s):
87568   88863   Bash/Shell/PowerShell;HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript...`
###Split the LanguagesWorkedWith column into  multiple columns  by using` data= data1['LanguagesWorkedWith'].str.split(';').apply(pd.Series)`.###
` data1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
data1.set_index('Responder_id',inplace=True)
data1
data1.loc[1,:]
data= data1['LanguagesWorkedWith'].str.split(';').apply(pd.Series)
data.head()`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), a package ports `dplyr`, `tidyr` and related R packages to python:

```py
>>> df
         i       j              A
  <object> <int64>       <object>
0       AR       5    Paris,Green
1      For       3  Moscow,Yellow
2      For       4  NewYork,Black
>>> from datar import f
>>> from datar.tidyr import separate
>>> separate(df, f.A, ['City', 'Color'])
         i       j     City    Color
  <object> <int64> <object> <object>
0       AR       5    Paris    Green
1      For       3   Moscow   Yellow
2      For       4  NewYork    Black
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code seems to work:-

```
new_df = df.assign(colname= df.colname.str.split(',').stack()).explode('colname')
```