# Convert string of different items in pandas dataframe with counts into categorical count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of several items, and how many quantities are present.
(x used to indicate quantity, x never appears in the item name)

```
                   items
    0                abc
    1  efg x 2, abc, def
    2            abc x 2
    3   efg x 3, def x 7
    4            abc x 5
```

I want to extract the items as individual components, and relate their counts:

```
         abc    def    efg
    0      1      0      0
    1      1      1      2
    2      2      0      0
    3      0      7      3
    4      5      0      0
```

---

What I've tried so far; from
[Pandas split Column into multiple columns by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600711/pandas-split-column-into-multiple-columns-by-comma#comment62687335_37600711)

```
pd.concat([df, df[1].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

This gives

```
                   items         0         1         2
    0                abc        abc      None      None
    1  efg x 2, abc, def    efg x 2       abc       def
    2            abc x 2    abc x 2      None      None
    3   efg x 3, def x 7    efg x 3   def x 7      None
    4            abc x 5    abc x 5      None      None
```

I have no idea how to proceed :/ and have been stuck at this for days.
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, even if the end product is not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
def extract_components(s):
    components = {}
    for sub in s.split(','):
        if 'x' in sub:
            prod, count = sub.split('x')
            components[prod.strip()] = int(count)
        else:
            components[sub.strip()] = 1

    return components

print(df['items'].apply(extract_components).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0))

  abc efg def
0   1   0   0
1   1   2   1
2   2   0   0
3   0   3   7
4   5   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Apologies I don't have enough reputation points so my upvotes don't show :/