# Split rows based on multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to split rows into multiple rows based on some column values?

My input dataframe is

```
   A              B           C
0  1  1234.0,5643.0     One,Two
1  2           5432  Three,Four
2  3  1278.0,5678.0        Five
```

I want to split the column B and C with ','. The output dataset to should be:

```
   A       B      C
0  1  1234.0    One
0  1  1234.0    Two
0  1  5643.0    One
0  1  5643.0    Two
1  2    5432  Three
1  2    5432   Four
2  3  1278.0   Five
2  3  5678.0   Five
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to turn the strings into lists then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) each one:

```py
df["B"] = df["B"].str.split(",")
df["C"] = df["C"].str.split(",")
for col in ["B", "C"]:
    df = df.explode(col)

#    A       B      C
# 0  1  1234.0    One
# 0  1  1234.0    Two
# 0  1  5643.0    One
# 0  1  5643.0    Two
# 1  2    5432  Three
# 1  2    5432   Four
# 2  3  1278.0   Five
# 2  3  5678.0   Five
```

In pandas v1.3.0 you can do a multi-column explode, but this requires lists be the same length in all columns.

Comment: I am using pandas 0.23.4. I don't think it supports explode.

Comment: That version is from August 2018, `explode` was added in 0.25 (July 2019).

Comment: @DumbCoder I think your options here are to either upgrade your pandas to at least 0.25.0 (which is still 2 years old!) or to [implement your own `explode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows).

Comment: in pandas 1.3 you can explode multiple columns, removing the need for the for loop

Comment: @sammywemmy see my note under the snippet. That will only work if all the columns have matching element counts, which in this case they don't

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
pd.concat([df[[0]], df[1].str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

More reference: [Pandas split column into multiple columns by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600711/pandas-split-column-into-multiple-columns-by-comma)

Comment: You aren't expanding both other the Series, `B` and `C`?