# Pandas dataframe, split data by last column in last position but keep other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Very new to pandas so any explanation with a solution is appreciated.

I have a dataframe such as

```
    Company                             Zip State City
1   *CBRE                               San Diego, CA 92101
4   1908 Brands                         Boulder, CO 80301
7   1st Infantry Division Headquarters  Fort Riley, KS
10  21st Century Healthcare, Inc.       Tempe 85282
15  AAA                                 Jefferson City, MO 65101-9564
```

I want to split the Zip State city column in my data into 3 different columns. Using the answer from this post [Pandas DataFrame, how do i split a column into two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two) I could accomplish this task if I didn't have my first column. Writing a regex to captures all companies just leads to me capturing everything in my data.

I also tried

```
foo = lambda x: pandas.Series([i for i in reversed(x.split())])
data_pretty = data['Zip State City'].apply(foo)
```

but this causes me to loose the company column and splits the names of the cities that are more than one word into separate columns.

How can I split my last column while keeping the company column data?

Comment: Its not right to edited the question after its been answered.

Comment: @Merlin wrote a comment on MaxU's question and needed to edit the post to show what I was asking. How would you accomplishing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [110]: df
Out[110]:
                               Company                 Zip State City
1                                *CBRE            San Diego, CA 92101
4                          1908 Brands              Boulder, CO 80301
7   1st Infantry Division Headquarters                 Fort Riley, KS
10       21st Century Healthcare, Inc.                    Tempe 85282
15                                 AAA  Jefferson City, MO 65101-9564

In [112]: df[['City','State','ZIP']] = df['Zip State City'].str.extract(r'([^,\d]+)?[,]*\s*([A-Z]{2})?\s*([\d\-]{4,11})?', expand=True)

In [113]: df
Out[113]:
                               Company                 Zip State City            City State         ZIP
1                                *CBRE            San Diego, CA 92101       San Diego    CA       92101
4                          1908 Brands              Boulder, CO 80301         Boulder    CO       80301
7   1st Infantry Division Headquarters                 Fort Riley, KS      Fort Riley    KS         NaN
10       21st Century Healthcare, Inc.                    Tempe 85282          Tempe    NaN       85282
15                                 AAA  Jefferson City, MO 65101-9564  Jefferson City    MO  65101-9564
```

From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
Series.str.extract(pat, flags=0, expand=None)
```

> For each subject string in the Series, extract groups from the first
> match of regular expression pat.
>
> New in version 0.13.0.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **pat** : string
>
> Regular expression pattern with capturing groups
>
> **flags** : int, default 0 (no flags)
>
> re module flags, e.g.
> re.IGNORECASE .. versionadded:: 0.18.0
>
> **expand** : bool, default False
>
> If True, return DataFrame.
>
> If False, return Series/Index/DataFrame.
>
> **Returns**:   DataFrame with one row for each subject string, and one
> column for each group. Any capture group names in regular expression
> pat will be used for column names; otherwise capture group numbers
> will be used. The dtype of each result column is always object, even
> when no match is found. If expand=True and pat has only one capture
> group, then return a Series (if subject is a Series) or Index (if
> subject is an Index).

Comment: WARNING!!!!!  Keep the zipcode as type string. The leading zero in some zipcodes  will be interpreted as hexadecimal.

Comment: @Merlin, what is wrong having ZIP as string? I've added a leading zero to the sample data set...

Comment: Good answer! +1 from me

Comment: @MaxU what does `expand = True` do?

Comment: @MaxU any idea how I can expand it to find both 5 and 9 digit code zipcodes? I updated my example to show this. I tried using `|` in regex, but I can't get it to capture either\or only either.

Comment: @MaxU ah that's smart. Thanks for the diligence!