# Pandas Dataframe, How can I split a column into two by "," when some rows may have more than 1 ","

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe. One of the columns is a combination of `CITY` and `STATE`. I want to split this column to two columns, `CITY` and `STATE` using:

```
df['CITY'],df['STATE'] = df['WORKSITE'].str.split(",")
```

And I got this error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df['CITY'],df['STATE'] = df['WORKSITE'].str.split(",")
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

So, I'm wondering is there a method that I can ignore the exceptions or detect which row is not working?

Comment: I'm not strongly familiar with Python, but I expect (based on my Perl sensibilities) `split` isn't really going to be the solution you need, because it will generate an array of varying length on the RHS, while your LHS is always an array of length 2.

Comment: You may be better-served to find the position of the first comma, then use substring methods to get the prefix and postfix.

Comment: [`.str.split()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) takes a parameter `n` which limits the number of splits, so `df['WORKSITE'].str.split(",", n=1)` should do what you want.

Comment: @Craig I've tried that and still not working.

Answer (score 3):

Set `n=2` in the `split` call and use the `str` method effectively:

```
import pandas as pd

x = ['New York, NY', 'Los Angeles, CA', 'Kansas City, KS, US']

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['WORKSITE'])

df['CITY'], df['STATE'] = df['WORKSITE'].str.split(',', 2).str[0:2].str

print df
```

**Output**

```
              WORKSITE         CITY STATE
0         New York, NY     New York    NY
1      Los Angeles, CA  Los Angeles    CA
2  Kansas City, KS, US  Kansas City    KS
```

I got some help from looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358924/3657941) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two).

Comment: This is great. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Happy that my answer inspired this one. I'd just add that, in this case, the `n=2` to the split is not strictly necessary (although it's good for performance in case there are pathological cases with lots of excessive commas).

On the other hand, neither `n=2` nor the slice notation protects against a `TypeError` if there are **less** commas than necessary.

In that case the developer would have to first split, then use the `.str.len()` method to create a column which would be used to filter rows with too few splits.