# Pandas DataFrame - Splitting Series Strings into Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

My question is more about the methodology/syntax described into a previous post which addresses different approaches to meet the same objective of splitting string values into lists and assigning each list item to a new column.  Here's the post:  [Pandas DataFrame, how do i split a column into two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two)

df:

```
                          GDP
Date                        
Mar 31, 2017  19.03 trillion
Dec 31, 2016  18.87 trillion
```

script 1 + ouput:

```
>>> df['GDP'], df['Units'] = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1).str
>>> print(df)

                GDP     Units
Date                         
Mar 31, 2017  19.03  trillion
Dec 31, 2016  18.87  trillion
```

script 2 + output:

```
>>> df[['GDP', 'Units']] = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
>>> print(df)

                GDP     Units
Date                         
Mar 31, 2017  19.03  trillion
Dec 31, 2016  18.87  trillion
```

script 3 + output:

```
>>> df['GDP'], df['Units'] = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
>>> print(df)

              GDP  Units
Date                    
Mar 31, 2017    0      1
Dec 31, 2016    0      1
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?  Why does script 3 produce these values in the output?

Answer (score 5):

Let's start by looking at this

```
df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1)

0    [19.03, trillion]
1    [18.87, trillion]
Name: GDP, dtype: object
```

It produces a series of lists.  However, the `pd.Series.str`, aka string accessor allows us to access the first, second, ... parts of these embedded lists via intuitive python list indexing.

```
df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1).str[0]

Date
Mar 31, 2017    19.03
Dec 31, 2016    18.87
Name: GDP, dtype: object
```

Or

```
df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1).str[1]

Date
Mar 31, 2017    trillion
Dec 31, 2016    trillion
Name: GDP, dtype: object
```

So, if we split into two element lists, `split(' ', 1)` we can treat the return object from an additional `str` as an iterable

```
a, b = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1).str

a

Date
Mar 31, 2017    19.03
Dec 31, 2016    18.87
Name: GDP, dtype: object
```

And

```
b

Date
Mar 31, 2017    trillion
Dec 31, 2016    trillion
Name: GDP, dtype: object
```

Ok, we can short-cut the creation of two new columns by leveraging this iterable unpacking

```
df['GDP'], df['Units'] = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1).str
```

---

However, we can pass a parameter to `expand` our new lists into new dataframe columns

```
df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)

                  0         1
Date                         
Mar 31, 2017  19.03  trillion
Dec 31, 2016  18.87  trillion
```

Now we can assign a dataframe to new columns of another dataframe like so

```
df[['GDP', 'Units']] = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

However, when we do

```
df['GDP'], df['Units'] = df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

The return value of `df['GDP'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)` gets unpacked and those results are simply the column values.  If you see just above, you notice they are `0` and `1`.  So in this case, `0` is assigned to the column `df['GDP']` and `1` is assigned to the column `df['Units']`