# Set index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the Olympics dataset related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table)

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
                Unnamed: 0  # Summer  01 !  02 !  03 !  Total  # Winter  \
0        Afghanistan (AFG)        13     0     0     2      2         0   
1            Algeria (ALG)        12     5     2     8     15         3   
2          Argentina (ARG)        23    18    24    28     70        18   
3            Armenia (ARM)         5     1     2     9     12         6   
4  Australasia (ANZ) [ANZ]         2     3     4     5     12         0
```

I want to do the following things:

- Split country name and country code and add country name as data
  frame index
- Remove extra unnecessary characters from country name.

For example the updated column should be:

```
                    Unnamed: 0  # Summer  01 !  02 !  03 !  Total  # Winter  \
0        Afghanistan         13     0     0     2      2         0   
1            Algeria         12     5     2     8     15         3   
2          Argentina         23    18    24    28     70        18   
3            Armenia          5     1     2     9     12         6   
4         Australasia         2     3     4     5     12         0
```

Please show me a proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame, how do i split a column into two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two)

Comment: What extra characters do you want to remove ? Can you show an example ?

Comment: Does the edit help? @SpandanBrahmbhatt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex and replace to that i.e

```
df = df.replace('\(.+?\)|\[.+?\]\s*','',regex=True).rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Country'}).set_index('Country')
```

Output:

```
               Summer  01 !  02 !  03 !  Total  Winter
Country                                               
Afghanistan        13     0     0     2      2       0
Algeria            12     5     2     8     15       3
Argentina          23    18    24    28     70      18
Armenia             5     1     2     9     12       6
Australasia         2     3     4     5     12       0
```

If you dont want to rename then `.set_index('Unnamed: 0')`

Or Thanks [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston) a much easier solution is to split by `(` and select the first element i.e

```
df['Unnamed: 0'] = df['Unnamed: 0'].str.split('\(').str[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had troubles on thinking how to split or use regex. Made it clear!

Comment: `df['Unnamed: 0'] = df['Unnamed: 0'].str.split('\(').str[0]`

Comment: @ScottBoston So sorry I dint see the `\(` there. So stubborn me.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting to get two columns, `country` and `Country Code` and setting country as index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.Unnamed.str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['Country', 'countryCode']).set_index('Country')
```

You could also add country code as an additional info in your dataframe.

Removing the extra thing, as I suppose like:   `[ANZ]`, using regex (as mentioned in other answer)

```
df2 = df2.replace('\[.*?\]','', regex=True)
```