# How to split a columns into 2 correctly with pandas in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, pandas, debian

I have got a lot of column in a csv, and I want to split a column into 2.

My column:

[image]

I need this format :

[image]

How can I split it? It is a little bit complex for me.

EDIT: I tried this one, but it isn't working.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv')
df[['Animals', 'Animals2']] = df['Animals'].str.split('(^\D+)', expand=True).drop(0,1)
df['Animals'] = df['Animals'].str.strip()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex and str.split with expand i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['Cat 3:30 pm','Hamster pig 4:30 pm','Cancelled']})
df[['Animal','Time']] = df['Animal'].str.split('(^\D+)',expand=True).drop(0,1)
df['Animal'] = df['Animal'].str.strip()
```

Output :

```
      Animal     Time
0          Cat   3:30 pm
1  Hamster pig   4:30 pm
2     Cancelled
```

Comment: I updated my question with your code, but it isn't work, what am i wrong?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test7.py", line 158, in <module>
    df[['Animals', 'Animals2']] = df['Animals'].str.split('(^\D+)', expand=True).drop(0,1)
  File "/home/web/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

Comment: File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 'Animals'

Comment: Did you read my edit with my code what i tried? Is it correct, sure?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv')
df[['Animals', 'Animals2']] = df['Animals'].str.split('(^\D+)', expand=True).drop(0,1)
df['Animals'] = df['Animals'].str.strip()

Comment: Sir its right. Either post sample of `test.csv` or `df.head()`. Key error resolving is done looking at the data not code believe me.

Comment: I see the problem now! I think i mistaked with the read ! Because there is 340 rows and 1 columns, what is bad! How can i read it with ; separate?

Comment: And how can I save it? Because the df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, sep=";") not working well

Comment: + how can i take it next to the Animals column?

Comment: Sir I have my assignments to write can't answer now will answer in mean time.