# Split a column's values by a special character and group by pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, group-by

I have a `df` like this,

```
Owner   Messages
AAA     (YY) Duplicates
AAA     Missing Number; (VV) Corrected Value; (YY) Duplicates
AAA     (YY) Duplicates
BBB     (YY) Duplicates
BBB     Missing Measure; Missing Number
```

When I do a normal `groupby` like this,

```
df_grouped = df.groupby([' Owner', 'Messages']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df_grouped
```

I get this as expected,

```
    Owner  Messages                                               count
0   AAA   (YY) Duplicates                                           2
1   AAA   Missing Number; (VV) Corrected Value; (YY) Duplicates     1
2   BBB   (YY) Duplicates                                           1
3   BBB   Missing Measure; Missing Number                           1
```

However, I need something (desired output) like this splitting by `;` inside `Messages` column.

```
   Owner    Messages             count
0   AAA    (YY) Duplicates       3
1   AAA    Missing Number        1
2   AAA    (VV) Corrected Value  1
3   BBB    (YY) Duplicates       1
4   BBB    Missing Measure       1
5   BBB    Missing Number        1
```

So far, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns), @LeoRochael's answer, it splits `Messages` column's values by `;` and puts into a list. Anyhow, I can not get the individual count after splitting.

Any ideas how to get my desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to unnest your original dataframe , then we just do group `size`

```
s=df.set_index('Owner').Messages.str.split('; ',expand=True).stack().to_frame('Messages').reset_index()
s.groupby(['Owner','Messages']).size()
Out[1213]: 
Owner  Messages            
AAA    (VV) Corrected Value    1
       (YY) Duplicates         3
       Missing Number          1
BBB    (YY) Duplicates         1
       Missing Measure         1
       Missing Number          1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I am still getting `AAA`'s `(YY) Duplicates` 2 and then another `(YY) Duplicates` 1 of them. You seem to get 3. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @i.n.n.m ('; ') have a blank after ;<space>

Comment: Is `expand = True` necessary here?... I got there by `df.loc[:, 'Messages'] = df.loc[:, 'Messages'].str.split('; '); df.set_index(['Owner'])['Messages'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()....`

Comment: t@Sotos If  adding `apply(pd.Series)` we do not need expand =True

Comment: @Wen I have a space too right after `;`. I tried @piRSquared's answer still getting the same reult, I don't get count 3 for `(YY) Duplicates`. I know I might be missing something simple, but can't seem to find it!

Comment: @i.n.n.m adding this line , `s.Messages=s.Messages.str.strip()`  before groupby

Comment: @i.n.n.m yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(
    Counter([(o, m) for o, M in df.values for m in M.split('; ')])
).rename_axis(['Owner', 'Message']).reset_index(name='Count')

  Owner               Message  Count
0   AAA  (VV) Corrected Value      1
1   AAA       (YY) Duplicates      3
2   AAA        Missing Number      1
3   BBB       (YY) Duplicates      1
4   BBB       Missing Measure      1
5   BBB        Missing Number      1
```