# Split a pandas dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

***Target***

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below and would like to split it where there is a blank-space, separating the "command" and the float value.

---

***Dataframe*** - `df`
e.g:

```
                                        0
...
432                   cl_bob_lower_amt "0"
433                      cl_bobamt_lat "0"
434                     cl_bobamt_vert "0"
435                        cl_bobcycle "2"
436        cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt "0"
437       cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt "0"
...
```

---

***My Attempt***

I have attempted to use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745484/5806746)

```
import pandas as pd
file_ = open("E:\\Location\\Tree\\123456\\730\\local\\cfg\\myconfig.cfg", 'r')
content = file_.read()
paths = content.split("\n")
df = pd.DataFrame(paths)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.row.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['command','value'])
print df
```

However, I seem to be receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'row'
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to identify why this occurs.

---

***Expected Outcome:***

```
                  command              value
...
432                   cl_bob_lower_amt "0"
433                      cl_bobamt_lat "0"
434                     cl_bobamt_vert "0"
435                        cl_bobcycle "2"
436        cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt "0"
437       cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt "0"
...
```

Ultimately I would like the user to be able to search for the command and change the value.

Comment: Make sure it is dataframe or series

Comment: @Wen Is it not a dataframe already?

Comment: @LearningToPython it could be a dataframe or a series.  From what you've posted, we can't tell which one.It looks like a series because we don't see a column header.  But you say it's a dataframe.  Those are inconsistent and Wen is asking you to clarify.

Comment: @piRSquared Oh, Okay. Thanks for the clarification. At the moment the column header is simply `0`. (Edited)

Comment: Try `df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['command','value'])` (I just replaced the reference to `df.row` (unknown column) by `df[0]` (the correct reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are attempting to call the "ROW" attribute for the DF, which does not exist. If you are attempting to do operations to select rows, I would suggest the .itterows() call to loop over just the rows you want at select indexes! Here is the best solution for what I think you are trying to achieve :)

```
import pandas as pd
```

Recreated Dummy Data

```
content = ['cl_bob_lower_amt "0"',
'cl_bobamt_lat "0"',
'cl_bobamt_vert "0"',
'cl_bobcycle "2"',
'cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt "0"',
'cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt "0"',]
```

Original Dataframe created

```
df = pd.DataFrame(content, columns = ['Value'])
```

Create a new dataframe (or re-assign to existing DF) by using .split call on Value.str

```
split_df = pd.DataFrame(df.Value.str.split(" ").tolist(), columns=["Command", "Value"])
```

Results:

```
                        Command   Value
0              cl_bob_lower_amt   "0"
1                 cl_bobamt_lat   "0"
2                cl_bobamt_vert   "0"
3                   cl_bobcycle   "2"
4   cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt   "0"
5  cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt   "0"
```

Comment: Appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['command'], df['value'] = df["0"].str.split().str

df

                                    0                       command value
432              cl_bob_lower_amt "0"              cl_bob_lower_amt   "0"
433                 cl_bobamt_lat "0"                 cl_bobamt_lat   "0"
434                cl_bobamt_vert "0"                cl_bobamt_vert   "0"
435                   cl_bobcycle "2"                   cl_bobcycle   "2"
436   cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt "0"   cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt   "0"
437  cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt "0"  cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt   "0"
```

If the column is an integer `0`

```
df['command'], df['value'] = df[0].str.split().str
```