# Data frame splitting

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, dataframe, split, timedelta

I'm having problems splitting a dataframe

Ex of data in data frame:

```
27/09/2017;2335W;0;;1"88485170"
```

I'm trying to split if with

```
data.split(";")
```

But I get
    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'

Any Idea of what I need to do in order to separate it? The first part is data, the second is time (I also need to erase the W) the 3 part is a number and the last is also a number

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta,time,datetime
data=pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")
data1= data.split(";",n=4,expand =True)
AttributeError: 'Data Frame' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv(...., sep=';')`

Comment: Try doing `import pandas as pd` at the beginning then do as @coldspeed say: `data = pd.read_csv("nameoffile.csv",sep=";")`

Comment: I already had pandas imported , its an excel file, sep =';' or sep=";" did not work

Comment: Can you please share the code of how are you creating a dataframe from the excel file? This will make us understand better.

Comment: See [How to split a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358924/222914)