# Split 1 column into 2 columns pandas dataframe AttributeError .str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The type is of course **pandas.core.frame.DataFrame**

The data is like this

```
res["created_at"]
0 2018-11-15 02:14:38
1 2018-11-15 02:14:20
2 2018-11-15 02:13:34
3 2018-11-15 01:53:18
...
```

I need to split "create_at" into "date" and "time" but when I try to do it based on this question [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns):

```
res['date'], res['time'] = res['created_at'].str.split(' ', 1).str**
```

or

```
res['created_at'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

I get the following error in both cases:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Comment: what is `res['created_at'].dtype`

Comment: Hi, is **dtype('<M8[ns]')**

Comment: Does `res.created_at.dt.date` and `res.created_at.dt.time` give you the values you want?

Comment: So it is not a `str` or `obj` type, it is a datetime format. @ALollz gives a good solution, I think

Comment: @ALollz effectively