# Split Pandas column into two two spaces after string

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have found some helpful [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns) of splitting columns, but none as specific as what I am trying to do.

I have a column with state & school information for a list of people that looks like this:

```
Col1
Miami, FLSchoolA
Charlotte, NCSchoolB
```

I want to separate after the string `, ST` but obviously the states are different. I would like this example to look like:

```
Col1             Col2
Miami, FL        SchoolA
Charlotte, NC    SchoolB
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: @JRibkr `.str.split` isn't particularly useful because here we need to include the splitting condition in the first string. It might be possible with a look behind, but the actual pattern to split on is empty, which might make it impossible. +1 to anyone who figures it out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.str.extract` for this with 2 capturing groups.:

```
df.Col1.str.extract('(.*,\s[A-Z]{2})(.*)')

               0        1
0      Miami, FL  SchoolA
1  Charlotte, NC  SchoolB
```

Comment: If you want to be truly pedantic and make sure you only include states, and not for instance, `, GH` then change the regex to `f'(.*,\s[{"|".join(states)}]{{2}})(.*)')` using `states` from @JoshFriedlander. But probably overkill, if your data are clean enough.

Comment: When I assign the `.str.extract` function to a column, I lose the second part of the split (the school). How can I store these in the data frame?

Comment: @a.powell. A safe alternative would be to concatenate the result `pd.concat([df, df.Col1.str.extract('(.*,\s[A-Z]{2})(.*)')], axis=1)` which will just append those two split columns to your original. But if you dont care about the original anymore, why not just use the `DataFrame` output above (just rename the columns)?

Comment: when I attempt to just use the data frame it returns the second column empty. Any clue why?

Comment: @a.powell I do not know. With your provided data the split seems to work, If you can create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem it might be best to ask another question as long discussions in comments are generally frowned upon. You can use `df.to_dict()` to easily provide us with the problematic data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.index` with slicing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Miami, FLSchoolA', 'Charlotte, NCSchoolB']})

def splitter(val):
    idx = val.index(',') + 4
    return val[:idx], val[idx:]

df['Col1'], df['Col2'] = list(zip(*map(splitter, df['Col1'])))

print(df)

#             Col1     Col2
# 0      Miami, FL  SchoolA
# 1  Charlotte, NC  SchoolB
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here don't seem to include the specific need to look for states. My suggestion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Miami, FLSchoolA', 'Charlotte, NCSchoolB']})

states = """AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME
 MI MN MO MS MT NC ND NE NH NJ NM NV NY OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VA VT
 WA WI WV WY""".split()

def splitter(ser):
    state = [x for x in states if x in ser]
    if len(state) > 0:
        st = ', ' + state[0]
        a = ser.split(st)
        return [a[0] + st, a[1]]

df.Col1.transform(splitter)
```

Returns a series of lists of two, which can easily be separated into columns:

```
0        ['Miami, FL', 'SchoolA']
1    ['Charlotte, NC', 'SchoolB']
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

There's probably a way to write this condition into `pd.Series.str.split`, so you can fit in the `expand=True` and do it in one step.