# Mapping columns value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that has a name and email column. My goal is to map a new column, which is to separate the column names into two columns, first names and last names. The following sample table.

```
Names, Email
aa bb, aa@bb.com
bb cc, bb@cc.com
cc dd, cc@dd.com
```

To be

```
First Name, Last Name, Email
aa, bb, aa@bb.com
bb, cc, bb@cc.com
cc, dd, cc@dd.com
```

honestly, I am currently only able to read files with Pandas, I have read a number of articles about mapping in Pandas, but I have not found the right one.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with expand equals true?

Comment: Also check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303523/4909087) to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
df[['First_Name','Last_Name']]=df.pop('Names').str.split(" ",expand=True)
print(df)
        Email First_Name Last_Name
0   aa@bb.com         aa        bb
1   bb@cc.com         bb        cc
2   cc@dd.com         cc        dd
```