# Append results from multiple SQL Queries into a Pandas Dataframe or Dictionary

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, dictionary, pyodbc

I am trying to loop through several SQL Queries and append the results for these queries in a dataframe or dictionary with the key being the SQL Query

I was able to retrieve results from these SQL Queries.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    cur.execute(row["SQL_Query"]) 
    print(cur.fetchall())
```

Output:

[(datetime.date(2019, 4, 8), datetime.date(2019, 4, 1))]

[(2, )]

[('6', 2), ('7', 2)]

[(13, 2)]

But when I try to add them to a dataframe, I am only able to fetch result from the last query.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    res = cur.execute(row["SQL_Query"]) 
    df['Results'] = DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
```

["Output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Gq1.png)

The goal right now is only to have results from SQL Queries in different columns. For instance, is the query return Total Count and Failed Count, then that be in 2 different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're iterating over the dataframe for queries and then assigning over df['Results'] each time.  You should apply an index value.

The below should work or at least get you on the right track.  I can't replicate this quickly to test it.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    cur.execute(row["SQL_Query"]) 
    df.loc[index,'Results'] = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I get a ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray. Should I be initializing the column before the loop?

Comment: Yes, I believe it should be initialized before the loop.

Comment: I did df['Results'] = [] before the loop. But this gives me ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Try ```df['Results'] = ''``` instead.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Do you have an idea about how would I be able to separate the result into 2 different columns (if the query results in 2 different columns)?

Comment: You can use a split method maybe.  I think it would depend on your output.  If you're outputting 2 objects you want to split you can check the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns