# Divide date+hour column into two colums (format date, number) with Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to separate these column into two, since Excel extract function just takes way too much I figured I could do it in Python with Jupyter Notebook, using Pandas. But I haven't really do this before, normally I would have data already treated so I am having difficulties.

I tried using excel but it takes forever.

```
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|        date + hour  |        date only     |    hour only    |
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| 01/01/19 01         | 01/01/2019 (formated)|   1 (number)    |
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+


+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|        date + hour  |        date only     |    hour only    |
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| 01/01/19 01         | 01/01/2019 (formated)|   1 (number)    |
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: ```df['date+hour'].str.split(' ', expand = True)``` You can split it on the space, then expand it to new columns, which you can then rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the discussion here will help a lot:
[How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns)

Basically, you want to use pandas.Series.str.split (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the string in your Date & Hour column into a list and then assign the two halves of that list into new columns.