# extract a dataframe that has both timestamp and location in the same row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there any easy way to extract a data frame that has both timestamp and location in the same row?

1 of the columns in this dataframe:

```
event
2019-01-01 11:08:33.000 USA
2019-01-02 11:08:33.000 Mexico
2019-01-03 11:08:33.000 Canada
```

Any easy way to separate them into 2 columns e.g. time and location?

```
time,location
2019-01-01 11:08:33.000,USA
2019-01-02 11:08:33.000,Mexico
2019-01-03 11:08:33.000,Canada
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) if no space in `location` strings:

```
df[['time', 'loc']] = df.pop('event').str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
                      time     loc
0  2019-01-01 11:08:33.000     USA
1  2019-01-02 11:08:33.000  Mexico
2  2019-01-03 11:08:33.000  Canada
```

Or regex solution with extract timespams with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
regex = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}) (.*)'
df[['time', 'loc']] = df.pop('event').str.extract(regex)
print (df)
                      time     loc
0  2019-01-01 11:08:33.000     USA
1  2019-01-02 11:08:33.000  Mexico
2  2019-01-03 11:08:33.000  Canada
```

Comment: the first solution works perfectly!  Learning a new syntax pop and rsplit! Thank you! @jezrael