# Split a pandas column into multiple separate columns depending on number of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
               Values   
                1,2
                nan,7,8
                4
                9,1
```

How can I split this column so that each value is now in its own column?

```
               col1       col2     col3 
                1         2
                nan       7          8
                4
                9         1
```

The only answers I have found are about splitting a column into two columns. [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns)

Comment: `df['Values'].str.split(',',expand=True)` ?

Comment: If check more answers there is also solutions for multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` with `expand=True`:

```
print(df['Values'].str.split(',', expand=True))
```