# pandas future deprecation on columnar iteration

Tags: python, pandas, deprecation-warning

I am getting this message:

```
Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases.
```

when running this line of code in python:

```
df['TB_mins'], df['TB_secs'] = df['TB'].str.split(':').str
```

(it splits the text in column `TB`, which is always of `'mm:ss'` pattern, into 2 distinct columns).

How can I avoid the warning, and still get the same result ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns).  >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns/51009917#51009917

Comment: `df[['TB_mins', 'TB_secs']] = df['TB'].str.split(':', expand=True)`

Comment: yep, it does, thankyou!