# Pandas FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing solution to split a dataframe with one column into 2 columns.

```
df['A'], df['B'] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', 1).str
```

Recently, I got the following warning `FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases.`

How to fix this warning?

I'm using python 3.7

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's not entirely correct, plus the trailing `.str` does not make sense. Since `split` with `expand` returns a DataFrame, this is easier:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

---

Your existing method without `expand` returns a single Series with a list of columns. I'm not sure what version of pandas used to work with your code but AFAIK you'll need to make some tweaks for this to work with pandas (>= 1.0) today. Assignment in this way is tedious but still possible.

```
s = df['AB'].str.split(' ', n=1)
df['A'], df['B'] = s.str[0], s.str[1]
```

I prefer the `expand` solution as it's a line shorter.

Comment: will the first answer work if my dataframe has more than two columns i.e. will I loose the rest of the columns by using df[['a','b']] =

Comment: Prior to pandas 0.16 the trailing str approach was, AFAIK, the main way to do this, so there is probably a lot of code out there getting this warning now.

Answer (score 3):

Or we do

```
df['A'], df['B']=zip(*df['AB'].str.split(' ').tolist())
df
    AB  A  B
0  A B  A  B
1  A B  A  B
2  A B  A  B
3  A B  A  B
```