# Is there a Python function that can rearrange column values into a specific column using CSV data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this column in our DataFrame that is separated by ';'. I managed to separate them but I was wondering if there was a way to put specific values into one column. For example, I would like to put Wayne State in one column, Oakland University in one column, etc. If this question has been answered already or if there is a similar post/question, please provide the link. I have looked and so far, I have not come across with the same problem.

[school_applied column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TZha.png)

[school_applied column separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLXu1.png)

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard). [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be downvoted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: `df.school_applied.str.split(';', expand=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney does df.to_clipboard work on google colab? i tried it and it's giving me an error

Comment: Try `df.head(10).to_dict(orient='records')` then paste the output into a code block.