# Pandas split into columns with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have something like this
I have a column in DataFrame like this

```
Column1
message1 message2 notmessage
message1 message2 
message1 message2 message3 notmessage
```

I want a data frame, like:

```
Column1                                 |  A        | b        | c
message1 message2 notmessage            |  message1 | message2 | null
message1 message2                       |  message1 | message2 | null
message1 message2 message3 notmessage   |  message1 | message2 | message3
```

There is no problem getting first value from the Column1 using

```
df['A'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(my_regex)',expand=True)
```

But how Can I obtain 3 new Columns?
I was trying using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358924 it worked for me when I was using split method in other files, but it doesnt work for me with regex splitting like below:

```
df.join(df['Column1'].str.extract('(my_regex)',expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'}))
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with select first column `0` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
d = {0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'}
df = df.join(df['Column1'].str.extractall('(my_regex)')[0].unstack().rename(columns=d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all 3 columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["message1 message2 notmessage",
                   "message1 message2",
                   "message1 message2 message3 notmessage"
                   ],
                  columns=["Column1"]
                  )

df['A'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(^\w+)',
                                    expand=True
                                    )

df['b'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(?<=\s)(\w+).*',
                                    expand=True
                                    )

df['c'] = df['Column1'].str.extract('(\w+3).*',
                                    expand=True
                                    )

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                                 Column1         A         b         c
0           message1 message2 notmessage  message1  message2       NaN
1                      message1 message2  message1  message2       NaN
2  message1 message2 message3 notmessage  message1  message2  message3
```