# Create a list from rows values with no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to extract the following words from a dataframe.

```
car+ferrari
```

The dataset is

```
                   Owner        Sold
type
car+ferrari         J.G         £500000
car+ferrari         R.R.T.      £276,550 
car+ferrari        
motobike+ducati
motobike+ducati
...
```

I need to create a list with words from type, but distinguishing them separately. So in this case I need only `car` and `ferrari`.

The list should be

```
my_list=['car','ferrari']
```

no duplicates.
So what I should do is select type car+ferrari and extract the all the words, adding them into a list as shown above, without duplicates (I have many car+ferrari rows, but since I need to create a list with the terms, I need only extract these terms once).

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT: type column is an index

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns)

Comment: The way you describe the task I am wondering why you cannot just type in `my_list = ['car', 'ferrari']`.

Comment: Type is an index column. I cannot type in my_list as I would like to create a build-in function to do this in case of many types

Comment: _Type is an index column._ Then convert it to a Series, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def lister(x): #function to split by '+'
    return set(x.split('+'))
    
df['listcol']=df['type'].apply(lister) # applying the function on the type column and saving output to new column
```

Adding @AMC's suggestion of a rather inbuilt solution to split series in pandas:

```
df['type'].str.split(pat='+')
```

for details refer [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split)

**Converting pandas index to series:**

```
pd.Series(df.index)
```

Apply a function on index:

```
pd.Series(df.index).apply(lister)
```

or

```
pd.Series(df.index).str.split(pat = '+')
```

or

```
df.index.to_series().str.split("+")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns

Comment: OP needs the list output from the delimited column values. It has not been mentioned that there is a requirement to split the column into two different columns!

Comment: In which case they would set `expand=False` when calling [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split).

Comment: I suggest you to add your opinion of solution as an answer. There are multiple ways to approach a solution. Everything is appreciated here. A not so good solution against a good solution only tells the community as to why one is better than the other. Cheers

Comment: @AMC that question does not answer my question as type is an index

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism, unfortunately I need to consider a split for Ann index column

Comment: @Val _that question does not answer my question as type is an index_ It absolutely does, all you need to do is convert the index to a Series.