# Split a string of category into specific Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a `Dataframe` column with following category:

```
    data = {'People': ['John','Mary','Andy','April'], 
             'Class': ['Math, Science','English, Math, Science','Math, Science','Science, English, Math']}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['People', 'Class'])
```

How may I create new columns and transform the `Dataframe` into:

```
> | People | Math | Science | English |
> ------------------------------------- 
> | John   | Math | Science |         | 
> | Mary   | Math | Science | English | 
> | Andy   | Math | Science |         |
> | April  | Math | Science | English |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to get a table of 1 and 0 for the `Class` column
- Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace 1 with the column name, and 0 with an empty string.
- `df.Class.str.get_dummies(', ').apply(lambda x: np.where(x == 1, x.name, ''))` creates a separate dataframe, which we use [`.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to combine back to `df`.
- [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the `Class` column, which is not needed.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

updated = df.join(df.Class.str.get_dummies(', ').apply(lambda x: np.where(x == 1, x.name, ''))).drop(columns=['Class'])

# display(updated)
  People  English  Math  Science
0   John           Math  Science
1   Mary  English  Math  Science
2   Andy           Math  Science
3  April  English  Math  Science
```

Comment: good use fo dummies :)

Answer (score 1):

Following code may help you

```
columns = set([x for lst in df['Class'] for x in lst.replace(" ", "").split(",") ])
for col in columns:
  df[col] = ""*len(df)

for i, val in enumerate(df["Class"]):
  cl = val.replace(" ", "").split(",")
  print(cl)
  for value in cl:
    df.loc[i][value] = value
df.drop('Class', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    People  Science English Math
0   John    Science         Math
1   Mary    Science English Math
2   Andy    Science         Math
3   April   Science English Math
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution,

```
# Strip-out white spaces before `,\s+`, use dummies to create categorical variable

df = df.set_index('People')

dummies = (
    df.Class.str.replace(',\s+', ",", regex=True)
        .str.get_dummies(sep=",")
)

   English  Math  Science
0        0     1        1
1        1     1        1
2        0     1        1
3        1     1        1

# Create a "hash map" to substitute categorical data
replace_ = {i : j for i, j in enumerate(dummies.columns, 1)}

# multiply keys with & replace to fill in the column values.
dummies.mul(list(replace_.keys())).replace(replace_)
```

---

```
        English  Math  Science
People                        
John          0  Math  Science
Mary    English  Math  Science
Andy          0  Math  Science
April   English  Math  Science
```