# How to insert list of list items in already created dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to fill list of list items into already defined dataframe row by row. Can you please help me how to do this?

I am really sorry I am changing my requirement.

Example:

```
list_item = [['1|x', '2|x', '3|-'],
             ['5|x', '6|-', '7|x'],
             ['9|x', '10|x', '11|-']]
```

Pre defined dataframe:
df

```
Name     Code     City  
Shiv     Sh       ALD
Kumar    KR       PJ
Ram      RM       KL
Shank    SK       RM
Jeet     JT       PKG
Atul     AT       FTP
Ganesh   GS       TL
Kishor   KH       KI
Gagan    GN       AK
```

Final Output:

df:

```
Name     Code     City  Num  Expr
Shiv     Sh       ALD   1     x
Kumar    KR       PJ    2     x
Ram      RM       KL    3     -
Shank    SK       RM    5     x
Jeet     JT       PKG   6     -
Atul     AT       FTP   7     x
Ganesh   GS       TL    9     x
Kishor   KH       KI    10    x 
Gagan    GN       AK    11    x
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns) with a trivial addition of flattening an array before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.ravel`:

```
df["new"] = np.array(list_item).ravel()

print (df)

     Name Code City new
0    Shiv   Sh  ALD   1
1   Kumar   KR   PJ   2
2     Ram   RM   KL   3
3   Shank   SK   RM   5
4    Jeet   JT  PKG   6
5    Atul   AT  FTP   7
6  Ganesh   GS   TL   9
7  Kishor   KH   KI  10
8   Gagan   GN   AK  11
```

---

After Updated Question:

```
list_item = [['1|x', '2|x', '3|-'],
             ['5|x', '6|-', '7|x'],
             ['9|x', '10|x', '11|-']]
s = pd.Series(np.array(list_item).ravel())
df[['Num', 'Expr']] = s.str.split('|', n=1, expand=True)

df
     Name Code City Num Expr
0    Shiv   Sh  ALD   1    x
1   Kumar   KR   PJ   2    x
2     Ram   RM   KL   3    -
3   Shank   SK   RM   5    x
4    Jeet   JT  PKG   6    -
5    Atul   AT  FTP   7    x
6  Ganesh   GS   TL   9    x
7  Kishor   KH   KI  10    x
8   Gagan   GN   AK  11    -
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am really sorry I changed my requirement. Could you please check and help me?

Comment: Please avoid changing requirements afterwards. This invalidates the effort people took to answer your question.

Comment: @shivam out of respect for others' time and effort, I would accept a solution and open a new question linking back to this for reference. You will also avoid an onslaught of negative votes.

Comment: @shivam I updated Henry's answer. Henry, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Its fine, but better is to assign both columns in one go using expand=True.

Comment: Good point, cs95 beat me to it. I was going to do `df[["Num", "Expr"]] = pd.Series(np.array(list_item).ravel()).str.split('|', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Not as well known, but `pandas` actually has a built-in `flatten` function for flattening lists (or any other container-like) of any level of nestedness. `flatten` returns a generator, so we need to wrap it in a `pd.Series()` (wrapping it in `list()` works as well- anything that will exhaust the gernerator) to retrieve all of the values.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.common import flatten

df["new"] = pd.Series(flatten(list_item))
```

---

Edit: Since you've changed your question. You can achieve the same result simply with the `flatten` approach:
We're flattening the list, and for each item we're splitting the string on the "|" to create a new list of lists (organized properly this time). We can assign this directly to new columns.

```
df[["Num", "Expr"]] = [item.split("|") for item in flatten(list_item)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am sorry I changed my requirement. Could you please check and help me to get this result.