# How would I transpose a column of values into individualized column titles

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a [dataframe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XehWLH6ODovnU5x7UWknZH4Omxe3bAtHRgLvXF8Wj0w/edit#gid=0) in which for each row, there is a column of comma separated text ordered somewhat randomly (`top_categories`) that is then separated out into individual columns (`Category 1`, `Category 2`, etc) based on their placement within the `top_categories` column.

How would I be able to get to my [desired output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XehWLH6ODovnU5x7UWknZH4Omxe3bAtHRgLvXF8Wj0w/edit#gid=1552211515), where each of the categories (**Category A**, **Category B**, etc) would be their own column (let's say ordered alphabetically), with a 1 or a 0 to indicate whether or not that specific category exists in that row's `top_categories` column?

Any help would be appreciated! (Additionally, I linked sample data in the hyper links above for what my data currently looks like (tab 1), and what I'm trying to achieve (tab 2). Thanks!

Comment: e.g. use last paragraph of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358924).

Comment: @jezrael Hi jezrael! Just looked through the linked solution you gave, and it doesn't seem to be the same as what I'm trying to do (at least to me). What I'm trying to do isn't simply splitting a column of delimited values of different lengths, but to have each of those column values become their own separate columns, with a 1 or 0 to indicate whether or not it applies to the original column value (see linked sample data).

Comment: oops, you are right, changed dupe link.

Comment: @jezrael oh yea, wow, this is perfect, thank you!