# Python read csv, split column to multiple columns and export to another csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file called **data.csv** which contains full address format separated by commas:

```
id;address
1;village1, parish1, county1
2;village2, parish2, county2
3;village3, parish3, county3
```

Using pandas, I would like to export those last 2 (parish and county) into separate columns from the right.

and export them as **exported.csv**

eg.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';')

...

df.to_csv('exported.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf8', index=True)

print ("Done!")
```

Note: those rows are over 100k

How to do that?

Comment: Have you looked into [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to create it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')
addresses = data.address.str.split(pat=', ', expand=True)
parish = addresses[1]
county = addresses[2]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'parish': parish, 'county': county})
df.to_csv('exported.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf8', index=True)
```

You can convert columns from a DataFrame into Series.str and call split.
I am unsure if there is a cleaner way to trim spaces, but in your case the separator has to have a trailing space if you want your fields to be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to do this but I was able to do it like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';')

address = df.address.str.split(',', expand=True)
df = pd.concat([df , address], axis=1)
df.columns = ['id', 'address', 'village', 'parish', 'county']
df.to_csv('exported.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf8', index=True)

print ("Done!")
```

The file 'exported.csv' using the example data you provided will look like this:

```
;id;address;village;parish;county
0;1;village1, parish1, county1;village1; parish1; county1
1;2;village2, parish2, county2;village2; parish2; county2
2;3;village3, parish3, county3;village3; parish3; county3
```