# Pandas Parsing by cell

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with n columns and n rows. Some of the cells contain multiple values seperated by ";" I can't figure out how to run through every cell in the dataframe and if I encounter this to sperate the cell into multiple cells.

[image: Example of the problem I am encountering]

The image above is in a google sheet but I need a solution for a pandas dataframe.

A appreciate any help in advance thank you :)

Comment: add your input and expected output as text not images

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df:

```
1 2 3 4
a;b;d; a;b g;a a
c;f f e g
e d
```

Try to do it via `explode`:

```
exploded = [df[col].str.rstrip(';').str.split(';').explode().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df.columns]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.columns, exploded)))
```

**df2:**

```
    1   2   3   4
0   a   a   g   a
1   b   b   a   g
2   d   f   e   None
3   c   d   None    NaN
4   f   NaN NaN NaN
5   e   NaN NaN NaN
```