# split column of space-separated values ​in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have dataframe with two columns with several values,devided by space:

```
first_column             second_column
Arkhangelsk P BP -       2.4 3.0 4.8 22.2
Koryazhma N - -          1.5 0.5 5.0 5.8
```

I need to devide tables in 8 columns:

```
0           1 2  3 4   5   6   7
Arkhangelsk P BP - 2.4 3.0 4.8 22.2
Koryazhma   N -  - 1.5 0.5 5.0 5.8
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
d1 = df['first_column'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
d2 = df['second_column'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
d2.columns = d1.columns + d1.shape[1]
res = pd.concat([d1,d2],axis=1)
```

**res:**

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Arkhangelsk | P | BP | - | 2.4 | 3.0 | 4.8 | 22.2 |
| 1 | Koryazhma | N | - | - | 1.5 | 0.5 | 5.0 | 5.8 |

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing this data from a csv? Because it seems you could use a sep = " " in the argument section of your pd.read_csv.

Comment: no, I imported it from pdf with use of tabula.read_pdf(file,pages=92)