# How to split two strings into different columns in Python with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to this, and I need to split a column that contains two strings into 2 columns, like this:

Initial dataframe:

```
    Full String
0   Orange Juice
1   Pink Bird
2   Blue Ball
3   Green Tea
4   Yellow Sun
```

Final dataframe:

```
    First String    Second String
0   Orange           Juice
1   Pink             Bird
2   Blue             Ball
3   Green            Tea
4   Yellow           Sun
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
df['First String'] , df['Second String'] = df['Full String'].str.split()
```

and this:

```
df['First String', 'Second String'] = df['Full String'].str.split()
```

How to make it work? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is to include the parameter `expand=True` in your [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to expand the split strings into separate columns.

Type it like this:

```
df[['First String','Second String']] = df['Full String'].str.split(expand=True)
```

Output:

```
    Full String First String Second String
0  Orange Juice       Orange         Juice
1     Pink Bird         Pink          Bird
2     Blue Ball         Blue          Ball
3     Green Tea        Green           Tea
4    Yellow Sun       Yellow           Sun
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I will accept the answer in 9 minutes

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this solution ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745484/15320403

`df = pd.DataFrame(df['Full String'].str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['First String', 'Second String'])`