# I want to split a column with multiple values as one

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

So my current column looks like this

| Name | New Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B,A | B |
| c | A |
| D,G | C |

So, some field have multiple value and some don't, how do i separate them into a single value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns)

Comment: What is the output you want here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want New Name column as my output

Comment: How does the value `C` come from `D,G` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it doesnt, so every value from the original columns gets moved to a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

try via [`upper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html),[`split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) method:

```
df['New Name']=df['Name'].str.upper().str.split(',').explode(ignore_index=True)[0:len(df)]
```

output of `df`:

```
   Name     New Name
0   A       A
1   B,A     B
2   c       A
3   D,G     C
```

Answer (score -1):

I’m not super familiar with tables but I’m sure you could still use string.split(“,”)

Comment: I tried that, it returns None for fields which don't have multiple values