# How to split a dataframe string column into multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe. This dataframe consists of a single column. I want to parse this column according to the '&' sign and add the data to the right of the "=" sign as a new column. Examples are below.

The dataframe I have;

```
                               tags
0                 letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C
1                 letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F
2                 letter1=G&letter2=H&letter3=I
3                 letter1=J&letter2=K&letter3=L
4                 letter1=M&letter2=N&letter3=O
5                 letter1=P&letter2=R&letter3=S
.                  .
.                  .
```

dataframe that I want to convert;

```
     letter1    letter2   letter3
0      A           B         C
1      D           E         F
2      G           H         I
3      J           K         L
4      M           N         O
.
.
```

I tried to do something with this code snippet.

```
columnname= df["tags"][0].split("&")[i].split("=")[0]
value =df["tags"][0].split("&")[i].split("=")[1]
```

But I'm not sure how I can do it for the whole dataframe. I am looking for a faster and stable way.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns/21296915#21296915

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this..

```py
import pandas as pd

tags = [
    "letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C",
    "letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F",
    "letter1=G&letter2=H&letter3=I",
    "letter1=J&letter2=K&letter3=L",
    "letter1=M&letter2=N&letter3=O",
    "letter1=P&letter2=R&letter3=S"
]
df = pd.DataFrame({"tags": tags})

df["letter1"] = df["tags"].apply(lambda x: x.split("&")[0].split("=")[-1])
df["letter2"] = df["tags"].apply(lambda x: x.split("&")[1].split("=")[-1])
df["letter3"] = df["tags"].apply(lambda x: x.split("&")[2].split("=")[-1])
df = df[["letter1", "letter2", "letter3"]]
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Split into separate columns, via `str.split`, using `&` :

```
step1 = df.tags.str.split("&", expand=True)
```

Get the new columns from the first row of `step1`:

```
new_columns = step1.loc[0, :].str[:-2].array
```

Get rid of the `letter1=` prefix in each column, set the `new_columns` as the header:

```
step1.set_axis(new_columns, axis='columns').transform(lambda col: col.str[-1])

  letter1 letter2 letter3
0       A       B       C
1       D       E       F
2       G       H       I
3       J       K       L
4       M       N       O
5       P       R       S
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d=list(df["tags"])
r={}
for i in d:                                            
    for ele in i.split("&"):                           
        if ele.split("=")[0] in r.keys():              
            r[ele.split("=")[0]].append(ele.split("=")[1])
        else:
            r[ele.split("=")[0]]=[]
            r[ele.split("=")[0]].append(ele.split("=")[1])

df = pd.DataFrame({i:pd.Series(r[i]) for i in r})
print (df)
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the PO wants... He is probably searching for the 'pandas' way to do it (which is most likely not looping through every single value of the dataframe)

Comment: Please add a description to your answer/code and use consistent coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
import pandas as pd
import re
tags = [
    "letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C",
    "letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F",
    "letter1=G&letter2=H&letter3=I",
    "letter1=J&letter2=K&letter3=L",
    "letter1=M&letter2=N&letter3=O",
    "letter1=P&letter2=R&letter3=S"
]

df = pd.DataFrame({"tags": tags})
pattern=re.compile("\=(\w+)") # Look for pattern
df['letter1'], df['letter3'],df["letter2"] = zip(*df["tags"].apply(lambda x: pattern.findall(x)))
```

Output

```
                            tags letter1 letter2 letter3
0  letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C       A       B       C
1  letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F       D       E       F
2  letter1=G&letter2=H&letter3=I       G       H       I
3  letter1=J&letter2=K&letter3=L       J       K       L
4  letter1=M&letter2=N&letter3=O       M       N       O
5  letter1=P&letter2=R&letter3=S       P       R       S
```