# How can I crate a transaction data frame by this raw data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, transactions

[image]

I have a raw data like this and I want to create a new transaction data frame group by customer_id like this
[image]

How should I do in python? Pleaseeeee~

Answer (score 0):

nisawaras, welcome to community (in the future the questions should be more precise)

[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) - [more info](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-the-split-apply-combine-strategy-in-pandas-groupby-29e0eb44b62e)

---

```
    data = {'customer_id': [1,1,2 ], 'menu_id': ['Cake','Water','Candy']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    grouped = df.groupby(['customer_id'])['menu_id'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
    grouped
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer❤️ but i want to create a new column as cake for column 0 and water for column 1 and candy for column 0 in new row 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Comment: It should help - The case to transform list of string into new columns