# How to split a column in csv file into multiple column in python jupyter?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter

Hello everyone I am learning python I am new I have a column in a csv file with this example of value:
[image]

I want to divide the column programme based on that semi column  into two columns for example

program 1: H2020-EU.3.1.
program 2: H2020-EU.3.1.7.

This is what I wrote initially

```
import csv
import os
with open('IMI.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    
    with open('new_IMI.csv', ''w') as new_file:
              csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter='\t')
              
    #for line in csv_reader:
       # csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

please note that after i do the split of columns I need to write the file again as a csv and save it to my computer

Please guide me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns might help - so would some examples of your before and after desired data.

Comment: Thank you but how to use pandas library  in the code  I wrote above ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('new_IMI.csv', sep='\t')
df
```

assuming that you're in a jupyter notebook this will evaluate your dataframe and show the data inside
you can access a specific column with `df['columnName']`
and specific line number with `df.iloc[lineNumber]`

Comment: I think reading csv with pandas should work, there is even a method `read_csv` maybe there is a different encoding than utf-8 which is why it fails to load.
If you can find out which encoding your file uses, then you could do pd.read_csv('new_IMI.csv', sep='\t', encoding='yourEncoding')

you can find out the encoding of your file with:
`
import magic

blob = open('unknown-file', 'rb').read()
m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME_ENCODING)
m.load()
encoding = m.buffer(blob)`

with csv library I don't know how to do it sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('IMI.csv')
df['program 1'], df['program 2'] = df['programme'].str.split(';', 1).str
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me a bit, how can I display all the rows in the result? cause now I get only colA and colB -> it is like all my data was stored in colA and colb

Comment: @AhlemMustapha What you're asking is very unclear. Please elaborate :)