# I need to split one column in csv file into two columns using python

Tags: python, csv

Hello everyone I am learning python I am new I have a column in a csv file with this example of value:
[image]

I want to divide the column programme based on that semi column  into two columns for example

`program 1: H2020-EU.3.1.`
`program 2: H2020-EU.3.1.7.`

This is what I wrote initially

```
import csv
import os
with open('IMI.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    
    with open('new_IMI.csv', 'w') as new_file:
              csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter='\t')
              
    #for line in csv_reader:
       # csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

please note that after i do the split of columns I need to write the file again as a csv and save it to my computer

Please guide me

Comment: `pandas` provides a *very* easy to use `.to_csv` method.  Perhaps do some research on this.  This can be used with the `.read_csv` method which will read the CSV into a `DataFrame` object where the column can easily be split, then written back out.

Comment: I did this but I was blocked : import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('IMI2.csv', sep=';',encoding='cp1252' it will bring parser error and if I do this it won't put data in the right format: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('IMI2.csv', sep=';',encoding='cp1252', names=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD','colE', 'colG','colH', 'colI', 'colJ', 'colK' , 'colL', 'colM', 'colN', 'colO', 'colP', 'colQ', 'colR', 'colS', 'colT', 'colU'])
df

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a column in csv file into multiple column in python jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258815/how-to-split-a-column-in-csv-file-into-multiple-column-in-python-jupyter) Please avoid asking the same question twice

Answer (score 1):

Using `.loc` to iterate through each row of a dataframe is somewhat inefficient. Better to split an entire column, with the `expand=True` to assign to the new columns. Also as stated, easy to use `pandas` here:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('IMI.csv')
df[['programme1','programme2']] = df['programme'].str.split(';', expand=True)
df.drop(['programme'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('IMI.csv', index=False)
```

**Example of output:**

Before:

```
print(df)
       id     acronym  status                   programme           topics
0  945358  BIGPICTURE  SIGNED  H2020-EU.3.1.;H2020-EU3.1.7  IMI2-2019-18-01
1  821362      EBiSC2  SIGNED  H2020-EU.3.1.;H2020-EU3.1.7  IMI2-2017-13-06
2  116026     HARMONY  SIGNED                H202-EU.3.1.  IMI2-2015-06-04
```

After:

```
print(df)
       id     acronym  status           topics    programme1     programme2
0  945358  BIGPICTURE  SIGNED  IMI2-2019-18-01  H2020-EU.3.1.  H2020-EU3.1.7
1  821362      EBiSC2  SIGNED  IMI2-2017-13-06  H2020-EU.3.1.  H2020-EU3.1.7
2  116026     HARMONY  SIGNED  IMI2-2015-06-04  H2020-EU.3.1.           None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` library instead of `csv`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('IMI.csv')
p1 = {}
p2 = {}

for i in range(len(df)):
    if ';' in df['programme'].loc[i]:
        p1[df['id'].loc[i]] = df['programme'].loc[i].split(';')[0]
        p2[df['id'].loc[i]] = df['programme'].loc[i].split(';')[1]

df['programme1'] = df['id'].map(p1)
df['programme2'] = df['id'].map(p2)
```

and if you want to delete `programme` column:

```
df.drop('programme', axis=1)
```

To save new csv file:

```
df.to_csv('new_file.csv', inplace=True)
```

Comment: if you want to iterate through each row, probably better to use `for i, row in df.iterrows():`  as the way you have it is dependant on if the index is numerical sequence from 0 to n.

Comment: secondly, if you want to drop the column, you'll need to reassign the `df` or use `inplace=True`

Comment: About first comment, i wrote this for data shown in the picture. And for second, yes, my bad. I forgot to write `inplace=True'.