# remove words from string in python

Tags: pandas, string, strip

I have a column in pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name
Apples 65xgb
Oranges 23hjkj
Bananas 76hhfk
....
```

Is it it anyway to get rid off of the ending of the string leaving only names of the product in the column?:

```
Name
Apples 
Oranges
Bananas
....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns)

Answer (score 2):

`df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split().str[0]`

Comment: This doesn't work for 'Green Grapes' for example.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the first phrase in the string

```
 df['Name'] =df['Name'].str.extract('(^\w+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a whitespace followed by a number, use:

```
# df = df.assign(Name=df['Name'].str.split('\s+\d+').str[0])
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split('\s+\d+').str[0]
print(df)

# Output
      Name
0   Apples
1  Oranges
2  Bananas
```