# How to apply pandas series extract method correctly?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, series

Want to separate each row value by dash and

After looking at [Andy Hayden's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21296915/17597459) answer

I’m grouping `U`, `33`, and `A, A`

using `(?P<Line>^\d{1,2}|^.|.*, .)`

out of the rows `U-2022W-ZZ5891` et. cetera

and trying to apply using `df[0] = df[0].str.extract(r'(?P<Line>^\d{1,2}|^.|.*, .)')`
and am unsure of how to continue the grouping to get from starting to final.

| col0 |
| --- |
| U-2022W-ZZ5891 |
| U-2014X-7073 |
| U-2010X-45 |
| 33-2010X-ZZ45 |
| A, A-2010X-45 |
| U-1996W-M-ZZ5891 |

from here ⬆️ (up arrow) to here ⬇️ (down arrow)

| col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U | 2022W |  | ZZ5891 |
| U | 2014X |  | 7073 |
| U | 2010X |  | 45 |
| 33 | 2010X |  | ZZ45 |
| A, A | 2010X |  | 45 |
| U | 1996W | M | ZZ5891 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
new_df = df['col0'].str.extract('(.+?)-(.+?)-(?:(.+?)-)?(.+)').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
      0      1  2       3
0     U  2022W     ZZ5891
1     U  2014X       7073
2     U  2010X         45
3    33  2010X       ZZ45
4  A, A  2010X         45
5     U  1996W  M  ZZ5891
```

Comment: Alternative regex `'(.+?)-(.+?)-(?:(.+?)-)?(.+)'`