# Cleaning csv column into fixed frame

Tags: python, csv, date, data-cleaning

sorry if it the wrong place to ask

I have a csv file with 12k+ rows and 2 columns[date,string] one of the columns have strings in it that most of them have 1-3 template that goes like:
["name(changes every row),fixed string, number, fixed string, number]
I want that every template will split into 3 columns [name, fixed_string_1 (with the number that follows it inside), fixed_string_2 (with the number that follows it inside)] and that every new row will have the same time stamp as the row it was separated from.

with what tool is it possible to do it in python ?  (and macOS)

Comment: Read the data using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Then you can follow this SO thread to solve the string splitting problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **pandas** library in python to clean your data easily.
and pandas documentation for CSV operations can be found at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

PS. the question needs more clarification. *If you can post a snippet of the csv file with various different types of rows in your CSV file then I can write a snippet of code that you can use.*

Comment: hey, thank you for the comment 
this how the most line looks like: "RSRUSDT rsi is 9.44 at price 0.037430. TF - 15mins" with date column "09.10.2021 02:26:22" and I want the first columns to be ["RSR", 9.44, 0.037430, 15]

but some of them looks like this "rsi alert for coins:\n\n BNB rsi is 9.98 at price 361.48. TF - 1hour\n\nADA rsi is 9.89 at price 1.0738. TF - 15mins" with date column "22.01.2022 08:28:57" - in this case I want to split it into to rows that shall have the same date as the original row had but will look like:
["BNB", 9.98, 361.48. 1]
["ADA", 9.89, 1.0738, 15]