# Pandas how to expand single column to multiple column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataframe like this:

```
    category
apple, banana, orange, ....
```

I just want to keep first item in one column then create another column for remaining items.
here is my expected dataframe1:

```
  category           sub category
       apple         banana, orange, ....
```

I want to make another dataframe where each items will be in a separate column. Here is my expected dataframe2:

```
    category           sub category1          sub category2        sub category3   
       apple              banana                   orange             .....
```

how to do that in pandas ? any idea?

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, you might start with [Split a pandas column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: @G. Anderson I tried pandas explode which expanding rows not creating new column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['category'].str.split(',',n=1,expand=True).set_axis(['category','sub category'],axis=1)
```

Comment: rhug123 thanks. can you explain little bit what exactly `n=1` doing here and how to also get my expected dataframe2  where each items will be in sperate column?

Comment: rhug123 also when exporting `df.to_csv` not seeing any changes.

Comment: `n =1` means to split only one time on the specified delimiter, and are you assigning the above code to the `df` variable? `df = df['category'].str.split()...`

Comment: If I add `df = df['category'].str.split()...` only category and sub category column exporting in my new csv but I also have few others column those are not seeing after exporting

Answer (score 0):

I always use

```
df['category'].apply(pd.Series)
```

it splits it into columns, then you have to rename them.