# Append list to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on a code like below, which slices the address column. For this I have created a dictionary and created an empty list `final` to append all the pre processing.see code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':  ['001', '002', '003'],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA"]

df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

final = []
for row in df_dict:
    add = row["address"]
    # print(add.split("\\n") , len(add.split("\\n")))
    if len(add.split("\\n")) > 3:
        target = add.split("\\n")
        target = target[-3:]
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    else:
        target = add.split("\\n")
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    final.append(target)
    print(target)
```

After preprocessing I am appending the empty list. Now, I want to update the `df_dict` with the `final` list. and convert the `df_dict` to pandas dataframe.

sample out put:

```
id  address
1   290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA
2   1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA
3   145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you means `df['address'} = final`?

Comment: You might want to look at a different way of doing that.
like discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Comment: you could run `df[address'] = df['address'].apply(your_function)` without creating dictionary.

Comment: yes df['address'] = final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assing to dictionary

```
df_dict['address'] = final
```

But you can assign directly to dataframe

```
df['address'] = final
```

You could even use `.apply(function)` to do it without creating dictionary

```
def preprocess(value):
    parts = value.split("\\n") 
    if len(parts) > 3:
        parts = parts[-3:]
    value = '\\n'.join(parts)
    print(value)
    return value
    
df['address'] = df['address'].apply(preprocess)
```

---

Full working code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':  ['001', '002', '003'],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

def preprocess(value):
    parts = value.split("\\n") 
    if len(parts) > 3:
        parts = parts[-3:]
    value = '\\n'.join(parts)
    print(value)
    return value
    
df['address'] = df['address'].apply(preprocess)

print(df)
```