# Occurrence not calculating correctly. Please Help Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, split

I have a data frame with the column countries like:

```
CHINA 
RUSSIA
CHINA
PAKISTAN/CHINA/RUSSIA
```

I want to count the occurrence of each country:

I did `df.Countries=df.Countries.str.split('/')` to get rid of the `/` and `df.Countries.value_counts()` this was the output:

```
[CHINA] 1
[RUSSIA] 1
[PAKISTAN, CHINA, RUSSIA] 1
```

How do I fix the counts for the multiple countries? Thank you!
Desired Output

```
CHINA 3
RUSSIA 2
PAKISTAN 1
```

So far it is not counting correctly.

Comment: Additionally, you can also refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .replace() method then the .split() method.

```
words = "CHINA RUSSIA CHINA PAKISTAN/CHINA/RUSSIA".replace("/", " ").split()
```

This returns:

```
['CHINA', 'RUSSIA', 'CHINA', 'PAKISTAN', 'CHINA', 'RUSSIA']
```

After that you can use the .count() method to count items in the list, and to avoid repetition you can use the dictionary.

```
countries = {country:words.count(country) for country in words}
for name, total in countries.items():
    print(name, total)
```

This returns:

```
CHINA 3
RUSSIA 2
PAKISTAN 1
```