# Split items on a dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have these items on a dataframe column and would want to split them into various components and have each component on a different column. For instance, I want to split `c5-0c0s9a0l14` so that i will have `c5 | 0|c0|s9|a0|l14`

I'm not sure how to do this but will appreciate any assistance with it

I tried doing this but it's not working

```
df[['item', 'val']] = df['COMPONENT_NAME'].str.split('-', expand=True)
```

see input and expected output format below:
[image]

Comment: post a testable input df fragment and expected output

Comment: Are you using Pandas? Please [edit] and add the tag for it.

Comment: What's the rule? Split on every dash or after every number? You could do that in regex.

Comment: Try looking at [How to split a dataframe string column into two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14745022/16653700)

Comment: I have edited my question to include the input and expected output format. I appreciate any help I could get. Thanks

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score -1):

Here, I have written the snippet for separating columns hopefully this will help you further. Also, attached the output so you have a clear understanding of it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Input': ['c5-0c0s9a0l14', 'c4-0c0s9a0l14', 'c3-0c0s9a0l14']})
df = df['Input'].str.split('-', expand=True)
print(df)
```

```
    0           1
0  c5  0c0s9a0l14
1  c4  0c0s9a0l14
2  c3  0c0s9a0l14
```

Comment: Thanks so much @wjandrea, I did this before but that not the output i need. I would like to split it into  c5  0 c0 s9 a0 l14

Comment: @maks Oh, I didn't post this, I just edited it.